# Zend_Form with HtmlTag decorator only over certain elements

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have the Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag over my whole form. What I would like to get is something like this:

```
<div class="form-elements">
    <div>
        <label>blah</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>blah 2</label>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-buttons">
    <input type="submit" />
</div>
```

How to get only certain elements inside HtmlTag(inputs here), and others inside other element tag? I have quite a few forms right now, so it would be great, if it'd be possible modifying only my base form class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this method to your base form class:

```
public function loadDefaultDecorators()
{
    $elementsToGroup = array();
    foreach ($this->getElements() as $element) {
        if ($element->getType() != 'Zend_Form_Element_Submit') {
            $elementsToGroup[] = $element;
        }
    }
    if ($elementsToGroup) {
        $this->addDisplayGroup($elementsToGroup, 'form-elements', array(
            'order' => 0,
            'decorators' => array(
                'FormElements',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=>'div', 'class' => 'form-elements'))
            )
        ));
    }

    parent::loadDefaultDecorators();
}
```

It loops through all the form elements and adds anything that isn't a button to a display group, which is then added to the form with a 'div' decorator overriding the default fieldset one. The 'order' param ensures that the elements will remain at the start of the form.

The div around the buttons you'll be able to do with a normal HtmlTag decorator on the button itself.

It's probably worth seeing if you can achieve the effect you want just using CSS instead of this, as this approach might cause you some problems in the future if you ever want to use display groups for what they were intended.